# Multiple GridSpecs in one Figure

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I was working through matplotlib's documentation (http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#adjust-gridspec-layout), and in this particular example I do not understand the logic behind the layout of two GridSpecs in one figure. The significant part of the code they use (leaving out text, titles and labels) is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

f = plt.figure()

gs1 = GridSpec(3, 3)
gs1.update(left=0.05, right=0.48, wspace=0.05)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[:-1, :])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[-1, :-1])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs1[-1, -1])

gs2 = GridSpec(3, 3)
gs2.update(left=0.55, right=0.98, hspace=0.05)
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs2[:, :-1])
ax5 = plt.subplot(gs2[:-1, -1])
ax6 = plt.subplot(gs2[-1, -1])
```

This gives the following result (http://matplotlib.org/_images/demo_gridspec03.png): [image]

These two GridSpecs seem to be aligned next to each other by default. Do I miss something in the code, that does this explicitly?

I tried to add a third GridSpec, like so:

```
gs3 = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)
ax7 = plt.subplot(gs3[:, 0])
ax8 = plt.subplot(gs3[:, 1:])
```

but this just fills the whole figure and the first two GridSpecs are "overpainted".

To restate my question, is there some implicit logic for the layout of two GridSpecs in a figure (note that I know of the method GridSpecFromSubplotSpec, but here it is not being used)?

Comment: Look at the alignment options: `gs1.update(left=0.05, right=0.48, wspace=0.05)` and `gs2.update(left=0.55, right=0.98, hspace=0.05)`. `gs1` ends at `0.48` and `gs2` starts at `0.55`, just like in your figure.

Comment: Where would you like the third `GridSpec` to be?

Comment: That is actually the answer. I just have not learned about alignment yet. If I update the third GridSpec with the parameters of the second, it takes the place of the second.

Comment: Ok, I formulated it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GridSpec` extent can be adjusted with the `update` command. With this line you limit the first `GridSpec` to the left side (48%) of the `Figure`.

```
gs1.update(left=0.05, right=0.48, wspace=0.05)
```

The second `GridSpec` is then limited to the right side of the `Figure` with

```
gs1.update(left=0.55, right=0.98, hspace=0.05)
```

Similarly you can limit the vertical extent with the keywords `top` and `bottom`.